# Lost Dropbox context menu entries, file and folder status indicators in Finder after updating to Yosemite

Tags: finder, macos, dropbox

I've lost all the Dropbox context menu options in Finder after updating to Yosemite. All indications of sync status on the files in my Dropbox location are also gone. The odd thing is, those context menu options are visible, along with the sync status for each file and folder, from save and open dialogs in applications. They've only gone away from Finder windows.

How can I get sync status and Dropbox context menu items back in the main Finder window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out Dropbox' self-updating wasn't functioning. The program was several versions behind current.

I was able to restore Finder context menus and sync status by going to [the Dropbox download page](https://www.dropbox.com/downloading), downloading and re-installing Dropbox. After getting version 2.10.41 the sync status indicators and context menus were returned to the main Finder windows when browsing under my Dropbox folder.

I did not have to uninstall or even stop the currently-running Dropbox service instance. The installer took care of all of that.

The latest Dropbox version that run properly with Yosemite is 2.11. Go to : https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=121399 and click on "offline installer" link for Mac OS X. Don't forget to restart your Mac after installation.

Comment: The current version is 2.10.41. Is that what you meant to type?

Comment: where did you find dropbox 2.10.41??? each time I go to dropbox download I get the 2.10.32 version [UPDATE]: found 2.10.41 on dropbox website (hidden page?): unfortunately after installing dropbox 2.10.41 OS x, the finder share menu is still missing OS X 10.10

Comment: I linked to the update page in the answer.

Comment: I tried Ian's instructions and it did not work the first time. The second time I quit DB, installed via the link, then restarted Safari, (cmd-option-esc-restart) and it worked.